# WinSCP scripting by feeding commands to StdIn in JScript - script hangs and never finishes

Tags: io, sftp, wsh, jscript, winscp

I'm trying to download about 40 files from SFTP server and it's downloading only 30 of them and hangs.
Pls help to fix the problem.

This is the script I'm using.

```jscript
var exec = shell.Exec("winscp.com /xmllog=\"C:\\download\\log\\download.xml\" "); 
exec.StdIn.Write( 
    "option batch abort\n"+ 
    "option confirm off\n"+ 
    "open sftp://xxx:xxx@xxx -hostkey=\"xxxx\" \n"+ 
    "get /download/* \"C:\\download\\\" \n"+ 
    "exit");
```

Please see the log below.
I wasn't able to find any problem in the log file:

```
> 2017-10-18 13:09:10.232 Type: SSH_FXP_REMOVE, Size: 54, Number: 99341
< 2017-10-18 13:09:10.233 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 99076
. 2017-10-18 13:09:10.233 Discarding reserved response
< 2017-10-18 13:09:10.235 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 99341
< 2017-10-18 13:09:10.235 Status code: 0
. 2017-10-18 13:09:10.236 File: '/compliance/2016_QTR2_DepreciationSummary.xlsx' [2017-10-18T17:07:08.000Z] [19819]
. 2017-10-18 13:09:10.236 Copying "/compliance/2016_QTR2_DepreciationSummary.xlsx" to local directory started.
. 2017-10-18 13:09:10.236 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2017-10-18 13:09:10.236 Opening remote file.
> 2017-10-18 13:09:10.236 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 63, Number: 99587
< 2017-10-18 13:09:10.239 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 13, Number: 99587
> 2017-10-18 13:09:10.239 Type: SSH_FXP_FSTAT, Size: 13, Number: 99848
< 2017-10-18 13:09:10.241 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 99848
> 2017-10-18 13:09:10.242 Type: SSH_FXP_READ, Size: 25, Number: 100101
< 2017-10-18 13:09:10.250 Status code: 1
. 2017-10-18 13:09:10.250 3 skipped SSH_FXP_WRITE, SSH_FXP_READ, SSH_FXP_DATA and SSH_FXP_STATUS packets.
> 2017-10-18 13:09:10.250 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 13, Number: 100612
. 2017-10-18 13:09:10.250 Preserving timestamp [2017-10-18T17:07:08.000Z]
. 2017-10-18 13:09:10.251 Transfer done: '/compliance/2016_QTR2_DepreciationSummary.xlsx' => 'C:\Users\Arman\Desktop\Work\pwc\final\servers\comerit_final_download_from_sftp\src\main\webapp\compliance\2016_QTR2_DepreciationSummary.xlsx' [19819]
. 2017-10-18 13:09:10.251 Deleting file "/compliance/2016_QTR2_DepreciationSummary.xlsx".
> 2017-10-18 13:09:10.251 Type: SSH_FXP_REMOVE, Size: 55, Number: 100877
< 2017-10-18 13:09:10.253 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 100612
. 2017-10-18 13:09:10.253 Discarding reserved response
< 2017-10-18 13:09:10.256 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 100877
< 2017-10-18 13:09:10.256 Status code: 0
. 2017-10-18 13:09:10.256 File: '/compliance/2016_QTR2_GainLossSummary.pdf' [2017-10-18T17:07:08.000Z] [120260]
< 2017-10-18 13:09:37.004 Script: Terminated by user.
. 2017-10-18 13:09:37.004 Copying "/compliance/2016_QTR2_GainLossSummary.pdf" to local directory started.
. 2017-10-18 13:09:37.004 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2017-10-18 13:09:37.004 Checking existence of partially transferred file.
. 2017-10-18 13:09:37.005 Opening remote file.
> 2017-10-18 13:09:37.005 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 58, Number: 101123
< 2017-10-18 13:09:37.009 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 13, Number: 101123
> 2017-10-18 13:09:37.009 Type: SSH_FXP_FSTAT, Size: 13, Number: 101384
< 2017-10-18 13:09:37.012 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 101384
> 2017-10-18 13:09:37.013 Type: SSH_FXP_READ, Size: 25, Number: 101637
. 2017-10-18 13:09:37.047 9 skipped SSH_FXP_WRITE, SSH_FXP_READ, SSH_FXP_DATA and SSH_FXP_STATUS packets.
> 2017-10-18 13:09:37.047 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 13, Number: 102916
> 2017-10-18 13:09:37.048 Script: exit
. 2017-10-18 13:09:37.048 Script: Exit code: 0
. 2017-10-18 13:09:37.048 Closing connection.
. 2017-10-18 13:09:37.048 Sending special code: 12
. 2017-10-18 13:09:37.048 Sent EOF message
```

---

This is the full working code after adding "var output = exec.StdOut.ReadAll();"

```jscript
var exec = shell.Exec("winscp.com /log=\"C:\\log\\download.log\" ");
exec.StdIn.Write(
    "option batch abort\n"+
    "option confirm off\n"+
    "open sftp://xxx:xxx@xxx  -hostkey=\"xxx\" \n"+
    "get -delete /compliance/* \"C:\\compliance\\\"  \n"+
    "exit");

exec.StdIn.Close();
var output = exec.StdOut.ReadAll();
```

Thanks
Arman

Comment: Show us a log file (`/log=c:\path\to\winscp.log`).

Comment: I've edited my question and added the log output. It looks like there is a limit . Is it possible that it's a SFTP server side problem? Or there is default limit on files to be downloaded?

Comment: It stopped at "2017-10-18 13:09:10.256" line and I've terminated the session from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show us, what you do after the `exec.StdIn.Write()`.

Make sure you read the program output, for example like this (as the official [JScript example for Access to Input/Output streams](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation_advanced#inout)) shows:

```jscript
var output = exec.StdOut.ReadAll();
```

---

See also [Capturing outputs of WinSCP process](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_dotnet#output) (the same problem, but for C#):

> You need to continuously collect the output while the script is running. The output stream has limited capacity. Once it gets filled, WinSCP hangs waiting for free space, never finishing.

---

In addition the to the above, you have to terminate the `exit` command with `\n`. Though in your case, it does not make much sense to provide the command using standard input. Just use [`/command` switch on WinSCP command-line](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting).

Comment: I've edited my question pls check it to see the full code. I've added var output = exec.StdOut.ReadAll(); line but it still hangs. Pls let me know what I need to change there.

Comment: never mind. I just moved exec.StdIn.Close(); line before var output = exec.StdOut.ReadAll(); and it works now. Thank you so much for your help Martin!

Comment: OK, you are actually missing `\n` after the `exit`.

Comment: yeah, I've added that one as well. Thanks a lot! It's working without any problem now.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I've used my privilege))